# Prove that the norms ||.||2 and ||.||infinity on a finite dimensional space are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that the norms $||\cdot ||_2$ and $||\cdot ||_\infty$ on a finite dimensional space are equivalent. I know how to do this with two integer values for the norms where for example $\displaystyle ||x||_p= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n|a)i|^p \right)^\frac{1}{p}$ and $p$ is a constant but not with infinity since $||x||_\infty=\max(|x_1|,...,|x_n|)$. Someone please help!

Comment: What does it mean for two norms to be equivalent? How do you show it for two $p$ norms where $p \in (0,\infty)$? Try using the triangle inequality on one of the $p$ norms to see if you can find whatever satisfies the definition of the equivalency of norms.

Comment: It should not be hard to prove.

Comment: two norms are equivalent if there exists c1,c2 >0 such that c1||x||p2<=||x||p1<=c2||x||p2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume the space is of dimension $n$. Then for any $x$, it is trivial that
$$\Vert x\Vert_2\geq\Vert x\Vert_\infty$$

On the other hand
$$\Vert x\Vert_2=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\Vert x\Vert_\infty^2}=\sqrt{n}\Vert x\Vert_\infty$$

Hence two norms are equivalent.

Comment: is there any way I can extend this to make it more simplified or clear to someone who hasnt seen analysis before?

Comment: I think this is probably the simplest and fundamental way to  do this.